# How can I remotely edit/update a text file using vim

Tags: bash, ubuntu, vim, redhat

I have to update a line on about 200 remote Linux servers.

Can someone please tell me if that't possible using ssh ?

Let's say I have 5 lines in the text file and I want to update a command on line 3 as illustrated below :

```
line 1
line 2 
line 3 # I want to update this line 
line 4
line 5
```

What command would I use remotely, using ssh, to get line 3 updated or add more text in it ?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: It depends on what, precisely, you want to do. `sed` (or better yet, `ed`) are more appropriate for non-interactive editing of a file, though `vim` can be used non-interactively.

Comment: Warning: when pushing a command out to a large number of computers, there's a risk that if the script isn't *quite* right, you could cause a large-scale disaster. Whatever you're going to do, test it well, and I'd put at least a little effort into disaster/rollback planning, just in case...

Comment: If you often need to work on multiple systems like that, look into `ansible`.

Comment: Agree with @Jack. You are asking "how do I chop 200 trees?", when you should be asking "how do I make a machine that chops trees for me?" See https://serverfault.com/questions/434197/how-to-manage-enterprise-network-of-linux-machines for some very good advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a bunch of ways you can do this.  The easiest way to modify a file is by using `sed`.  So if you want to modify line 3 in a certain way on each server, you could do something like this:

```
cat list-of-servers | xargs -I{} ssh {} sed -i -e '3s/line/ligne/' FILE
```

`sed` is a standard Unix command, so it should be available.  If you need something more complex, you can do it with `perl -i` or `ruby -i`, which are also good at this.  A `/usr/bin/perl` binary (with a subset of core Perl modules) will be available on all Debian and Ubuntu systems, since it's part of an essential package, but may not be available on Red Hat or CentOS systems.

If you really want to do it with Vim, you can; all of the colon commands are available in `ex`, and you can use `ex` to modify a file.  Note that the normal mode commands are not usually available here.  So you could write something like the following:

```
cat list-of-servers | \
   xargs -I{} ssh {} 'echo '\''3s/line/ligne/ | wq'\'' | ex -s FILE'
```

In this case, you could just use double quotes instead of escaping single quotes, but in your case that might not be possible, so I've demonstrated how to nest single quotes, since that's tricky.

Note that `ed` can also be used for this, but it's actually less common to find on servers than Vim since it's usually only installed as a dependency of `patch`, whereas most servers will have some version of `ex` and `vi` installed for the benefit of the sysadmin.

Comment: I'd recommend using something like `sed -i.bkp` instead of just `sed -i` so you have a backup file in case you need to roll back the change.

Comment: ed is required by POSIX, no? I use it occasionally and would be disturbed to find it missing

Comment: `ed` is required by POSIX, but not always installed by default on Linux systems.  Regardless of how we feel about that, it is indeed the case.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, consider bring the files locally, preparing the updated version on you local machines, and then shipping the updates. This will allow you to test the updated version before sending it around - less risk, better sleep.

1. Copy all the files to local box (to hostname-FILE)

```
cat list-of-servers | xargs -I{} sh -c 'scp $1:/path/to/FILE $1-FILE' -- {}
```

2. Make changes on the local system
3. Verify output
4. Update remote systems

```
cat list-of-servers | xargs -I{} sh -c 'scp $1-FILE $1:/path/to/FILE' -- {}
```